# How to hide #div from href attribute in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have anchor tag with href attribute like that `<a onclick='loadReview(\"" + strexternalURL + "\");' href='#productName1'` it displays in URL like `http://localhost:54986/Dealerlist.aspx#productName1` I want hide **#productName1** from the URL.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: if you are not using this id value on new page then remove it and leave it blank, or can use return false

Comment: -1 Give a little help in order for us to understand what you want to do. Your question is currently so poorly detailled that there are at least two possible interpretations. 1. You want to hide `#productName1` without reloading the page. 2. You want to hide `#productName1` after the page has reloaded. Please have mercy on the readers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use return false statement. Something like this :

```
<a 
  href='#productName1' 
  onclick='loadReview(\"" + strexternalURL + "\");return false;'
>
  Link
</a>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Format your hyperlink like such:

```
<a href="urlGoesHere">TextToDisplayGoesHere</a>
```

Comment: actually my javascript function that is loadReview which I written on onclick event is redirecting to other page and then I have to load this div which has the id as #productName1